R Package PGMM: Displaying number of instruments for System GMM Estimator
I am using a system GMM (generalized method of moments)-estimator with the pgmm R package for my finance thesis and would like to display the number of instruments used.
Is there a way to display it or calculate it? To make my question more accessible, find below a built-in data package (employment uk) to reproduce my question.
This is the code I created so far (edit 17th of august):
# Load the package and data
library(plm)
data("EmplUK")

# Estimate the dynamic model with Two-step System GMM
dyn_model <- pgmm(log(emp) ~ lag(log(emp), 1) + 
                  lag(log(wage), 0:1) + lag(log(capital), 0:1) | 
                    lag(log(emp), 2:99) + lag(log(wage), 2:99) + 
                    lag(log(capital), 2:99),
                  data = EmplUK, 
                  effect = "twoways", 
                  model = "twosteps", 
                  transformation = "ld", 
                  collapse = TRUE
)

For more info on plm usage find I link this intro blogpost I came across: https://tilburgsciencehub.com/topics/analyze/causal-inference/panel-data/system-gmm/
Best regards

Hi, welcome to SO! First we would need some Minimal Reproductible Example data to understand your needs, for example please add a small fraction of your data (see also here). Is the number of instruments one of your variables?

Hi Julien
Many thanks for your comment. How can I upload example data? So I instrument all my variables (roa, gov, size, growth,lev,capexp) and I use all lags available for instrumentation (meaning forendogenous variables, that means lags 2 and up until 99, for predetermined varibales lags 1 and up until 99 as suggested by Roodman 2009 p.108). Unfortunately I think that pgmm does not automatically display instrument count like stata. Can you help me with that?

See the links I provided in my previous comment (second one especially for R data) to know how to share some data. What do you mean by "I instrument all my variables"? Are variables available as columns in a dataframe? What's the relationship between these variables and the number of instruments? What is an "instrument"?

Hi Julien
Many thanks for your answer. to make my question more accessible I adjusted my question post so one can use a built-in dataset.
My personal definition of an instrument variable: an instrument is a variable that is used to control for endogeneity by being correlated with the endogenous explanatory variables but uncorrelated with the error term.
Yes, the variables are available as columns in the dataframe.

I am not familiar with these concepts but someone asked the same question in this post, you might be able to calculate the number of instruments used as described by the answer there

Thank you for the link, I gives me an idea. Unfortunately it will not be to do a recalculation based on that.
